# JBoss Active Thread Count affects Performance

Tags: java, jboss, threadpool

Can anyone help please, I have some applications deployed on JBoss, I have increased the maxThreads on JBoss Connector to 2000. I noticed at intervals, the number of active threads on my JBoss keeps increasing, when it gets above 400, JBoss stops processing requests even though the number of active threads keeps growing, at some point, the threads drop again and transactions start processing normally.

Does anyone have an idea of whats wrong wth the JBoss configuration?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have? Are you seeing GC pauses at this time? Are you sure no other resource is being overutilised?

Comment: Hi Peter Lawrey, thanks for your feedback. I am not sure other resources are being overutilised. I have checked the memory and cpu time and I think its bee ok. How do I check for GC Pauses?

Comment: You can run JBox with `-verbose:gc` or run `jstat {pid}` or use VisualVM.  If you have more threads than CPUs and you are not IO bounds, most likely you have more threads than is optimal.